# 2006 Ford Ranger XLT (Idaho)

Tags: ford, ranger, 4wd

My 4WD works well using Low4WD
When I switch back to 2WD the light stays in Low4WD, and it does this sporadically.
What is the actual part controlling this? An actuator, a solenoid?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Ranger actually allows you to put it into 2wd low range?

Comment: Why does "Idaho" appear in the title?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issues in my opinion are:

1. The 2WD/4WD sensor is failing and it doesn't read the proper setting.
2. The shift solenoid in or on the 4WD transfer case is failing or sticking and not actually shifting.

You might get yourself a helper who can activate the 2WD/4WD selection while you get under the vehicle (using properly safety precautions of course!) and see if you can determine of the problem is the shift mechanism itself or just the sensor.  You might also look for frayed or otherwise damaged wiring.